# Interview: random3 function implementation using random2

Tags: math, random, statistics

On recent interview I was asked the following question. There is a function `random2()`, wich returns 0 or 1 with equal probability (0.5). Write implementation of `random4()` and `random3()` using `random2()`.
It was easy to implement `random4()` like this

```
if(random2())
  return random2();
return random2() + 2;
```

But I had difficulties with `random3()`. The only realization I could represent:

```
uint32_t sum = 0;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
  sum += random2();
return sum % 3;
```

This implementation of `random4()` is based only my intuition only. I'm not sure if it is correct actually, because I can't mathematically prove its correctness. Can somebody help me with this question, please.

Comment: For the dim among us, what are `random4()` and `random3()` supposed to return ?

Comment: what is `N` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I would guess `randomN()` should return `0,1,2,...,N-1` with equal probability.

Comment: @Dukeling yes you are right.@high-performance-mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**random3:**

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but here's my take:

x = random2 + 2*random2

What can happen:

```
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 2 = 2
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
```

The above are all the possibilities of what can happen, thus each has equal probability, so...

(`p(x=c)` is the probability that x = c)

```
p(x=0) = 0.25
p(x=1) = 0.25
p(x=2) = 0.25
p(x=3) = 0.25
```

Now while x = 3, we just keep generating another number, thus giving equal probability to 0,1,2. More technically, you would distribute the probability from x=3 across all of them repeatedly such that p(x=3) tends to 0, thus the probability of the others will tend to 0.33 each.

Code:

```
do
  val = random2() + 2*random2();
while (val != 3);
return val;
```

**random4:**

Let's run through your code:

```
if(random2())
  return random2();
return random2() + 2;
```

First call has 50% chance of 1 (true) => returns either 0 or 1 with 50% * 50% probability, thus 25% each

First call has 50% chance of 0 (false) => returns either 2 or 3 with 50% * 50% probability, thus 25% each

Thus your code generates 0,1,2,3 with equal probability.

**Update inspired by e4e5f4's answer:**

For a more deterministic answer than the one I provided above...

Generate some large number by calling `random2` a bunch of times and mod the result by the desired number.

This won't be exactly the right probability for each, but it will be close.

So, for a 32-bit integer by calling `random2` 32 times, target = 3:

Total numbers: 4294967296
Number of x's such that x%3 = 1 or 2: 1431655765
Number of x's such that x%3 = 0: 1431655766
Probability of 1 or 2 (each): 0.33333333325572311878204345703125
Probability of 0: 0.3333333334885537624359130859375

So within 0.00000002% of the correct probability, seems pretty close.

Code:

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
  sum = 2*sum + random2();
return sum % N;
```

**Note:**

As pjr pointed out, this is, in general, far less efficient than the rejection method above. The probability of getting to the same number of calls of `random2` (i.e. 32) (assuming this is the slowest operation) with the rejection method is `0.25^(32/2) = 0.0000000002 = 0.00000002%`. This together with the fact that this method isn't exact, gives way more preference to the rejection method. Lower this number decreases the running time, but increases the error, and it would probably need to be lowered quite a bit (thus reaching a high error) to approach the average running time of the rejection method.

It is useful to note the above algorithm has a *maximum* running time. The rejection method does not. If your random number generator is totally broken for some reason, it could keep generating the rejected number and run for quite a while or forever with the rejection method, but the for-loop above will run 32 times, regardless of what happens.

Comment: Rejecting will be far more efficient than calling random2 32 times.  At each iteration you have probability 3/4 of stopping and 1/4 of rejecting and looping.  In the long run you'll terminate after an average of 4/3 iterations and require 8/3 calls to random2, plus the results will have an exact rather than an approximate probability of 1/3.

Comment: @Dukeling Long run times for the rejection method mean random2 isn't meeting its spec of p(0) = p(1) = 1/2.  You're correct that the 32 call version is bounded, but I'm willing to take a 2E-10 chance of exceeding that bound for a single call.  If we talk about a sequence of calls, the probability that the rejection sequence is longer than the bounded sequence very quickly approaches the range of probabilities that all the atoms in my body dodge around all the atoms in the floor and I end up in the basement.  Not something I'm going to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

Using modulo(`%`) is not recommended because it introduces bias. Mapping will be *nice* only if `n` is power of `2`. Otherwise some kind of rejection is involved as suggested by other answer.

Another generic approach would be to emulate built-in PRNGs by -

- Generate 32 `random2()` and map it to a 32-bit integer
- Get random number in range `(0,1)` by dividing it by max integer value
- Simply multiply this number by `n` (=3,4...73 so on) and `floor` to get desired output

Comment: Very interesting solution for generating 32-bit random number. I like it, thanks.